# How to Redirect After Successful Registration Confirmation

Tags: users, redirect

When a user registers on the front-end of our site, we'd like the default behavior be that when they click on the confirmation link in the email they receive, they are automatically logged in and taken to a "My Account" page that we've created. Is this possible? Right now, they're redirected to the home page, and it doesn't appear that they're logged in.

We updated the [postLoginRedirect](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#postLoginRedirect) variable in our config to the My Account page, but that didn't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The config settings you're looking for are probably '[activateAccountSuccessPath](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#activateAccountSuccessPath)' and '[autoLoginAfterAccountActivation](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#autoLoginAfterAccountActivation)'.

Comment: I would expect that the [autoLoginAfterAccountActiviation](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#autoLoginAfterAccountActivation) would accomplish the goal of logging them in immediately. Why does this not work?

Comment: Ahh, yeah.  Forgot about that one.  Will update the answer.

Comment: autoLoginAfterAccountActivation doesn't seem to be working for us. activateAccountSuccessPath is working.

Comment: You have it set to true? (no quotes)

Comment: Ah, my bad. I had quotes around 'true'. Now it's working as expected - thanks!